# Bracket for dual pair (in functional analysis)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, typography, brackets, delimiters

In functional analysis, one occasionally considers a so-called *dual pair* (a pair of vector spaces tied together by a non-degenerate bilinear map to the ground field). I usually typeset these using `\langle` and `\rangle`, but it seems that all textbooks in functional analysis use a slightly different symbol for this. (See samples below.) The shape is very similar to `\langle` and `\rangle`, but the angle between the two legs is noticeably smaller. Consequently, the glyph is a bit wider.

How do I reproduce this symbol in LaTeX?

---

**Samples:**

1. LaTeX with `\langle` and `\rangle`:

   [image: LaTeX-langle-rangle]
2. H. H. Schaefer, with M. P. Wolff, *Topological Vector Spaces*, Second Edition (1999), p. 123:

   [image: Schaefer]
3. Walter Rudin, *Functional Analysis*, Second Edition (1991), p. 93:

   [image: Rudin]
4. John B. Conway, *A Course in Functional Analysis* (1985), p. 127:

   [image: Conway]
5. Gert K. Pedersen, *Analysis Now*, Corrected second printing (1995), p. 59:

   [image: Pedersen]
6. Mahlon M. Day, *Normed Linear Spaces*, Second printing corrected (1962), p. 8:

   [image: Day]

... and the list goes on and on.

Comment: I like the typography :-). For my low opinion peraphs the last solution (1962) not will have LaTeX the same symbols. Something of similar I think yes.

Comment: I wouldn't worry; slightly different typographic choices don't affect the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fit the style of the default font, you can use the `mathabx` fonts. Here is how to use the `langle, \rangle` from `mathabx` without overwriting the default fonts. I added a `\Braket` macro, which uses the mathabx symbols, and has variable size if needed, thanks to the `DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

 \DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
 \DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
 matha7 <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9 <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12 }{}
 \DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

 \DeclareMathSymbol{\mylangle}{\mathopen}{matha}{"78}
 \DeclareMathSymbol{\myrangle}{\mathclose}{matha}{"79}

 \DeclareMathSymbol{\asymp}{\mathrel}{matha}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\notasymp}{\mathrel}{matha}{"1E}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\Langle}{\mathopen}{matha}{"78}
                                        {mathx}{"40}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\Rangle}{\mathclose}{matha}{"79}
                                        {mathx}{"44}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Braket}\Langle\Rangle

\begin{document}


\[ \Braket*{ x, \varphi } \]%
\[ \langle x, \varphi \rangle\]%
\[ \Braket[\big]{x, \varphi} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here I can give you some examples.

**1)** with `mtpro2`, v. `lite` (no pay):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
$\braket{F,G}$, 
$\braket{x,x^{*}}$, $\braket{x,\varphi}$, $\braket{x,y}$
\end{document}
```

If you use the pro version you will get this:
[image]

**2)** with the use of `newtxmath` you will have the same characters of `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`: https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
$\braket{F,G}$, 
$\braket{x,x^{*}}$, $\braket{x,\varphi}$, $\braket{x,y}$
\end{document}
```

**3)** Instead, using `fourier` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
$\braket{F,G}$, 
$\braket{x,x^{*}}$, $\braket{x,\varphi}$, $\braket{x,y}$
\end{document}
```

**4)** With `mathpazo`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
$\braket{F,G}$, 
$\braket{x,x^{*}}$, $\braket{x,\varphi}$, $\braket{x,y}$
\end{document}
```

Into this link there is the LaTeX Font Catalogue with math support. 
https://tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html.

It is important to explain hat some of the mathematical fonts it is essential the use of `XeLaTeX` (https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/XeLaTeX) or `LuaLaTeX` (http://www.luatex.org/).

Answer (score 3):

In the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math`, you can select a different math font of your choice.  The [list of symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) includes samples of a half-dozen different versions of `\langle` and `\rangle`.  You might also take a look at `\lcurvyangle` and `\rcurvyangle`.

Here, for example, is the output with STIX Two Math, which you can also use in PDFLaTeX through the `stix2` package.

[image: STIX Two Math Sample]

It is also possible to mix-and-match symbols from different math fonts.  Here is an example that uses only the angle brackets from STIX Two with the default math font, Latin Modern Math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\langle,\rangle},
             Scale=MatchUppercase
            ]{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
\( \langle x, \varphi \rangle \)
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two/Latin Modern sample]

Flavor to taste.  For example, Day’s book appears to be set in Palatino, which you might approximate with Asana Math or TeX Gyre Pagella Math today.